# Created an appointment in CRM Dynamics 365 using C#, But that is Not Coming into Outlook Calendar

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, office365, dynamics-365, appointment

I am following this link [Book An Appointment In CRM Dynamics Using C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/sample-book-appointment) and am able to create the appointment in CRM Dynamics Calendar, which in turn returns the GUID and it's visible in Dynamics Calendar too. 
Also, I was able to change the Appointment status from "open" to "Scheduled" by using entity `SetStateRequest` as follows but still I can't get this appointment synced/visible into my Outlook Calendar.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
Guid _appointmentId = organizationService.Create(appointment);

var state = new SetStateRequest
{State = new OptionSetValue(3),
Status = new OptionSetValue(5),
EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("appointment", _appointmentId)};

var stateSet = (SetStateResponse)organizationService.Execute(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

CRM & Exchange mailbox is still not connected using Server side sync. You have to configure your CRM mailbox record to sync the Appointment, Contact & Task (can be configured only in any one of the environment)

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/144170)

Go to your CRM system user record & open the associated Mailbox record, verify the Mailbox is configured properly for Incoming/Outgoing/ACT, O365 global admin approval, then “Test & Enable”.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/administering-dynamics-365/mt622056%28v%3Dcrm.8%29)

Comment: Thanks so much @Arun, I will try the guidelines and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Upon checking the same, i see the settings are right in place , so any clue on how to make any appointment tracked  in CRM using C# code? as there is a process called track/untrack while creating any new appointment using CRM Dynamics App

Comment: @ParthaDas the original question was about crm to outlook (sync by SSS), now we are talking about outlook to crm (track/untrack) completely different. There may be some rules (filters) to sync which you are missing here. If you are trying to mimic the platform track/untrack functionality on your own you have to talk to MS & reinvent it. As per StackOverflow norms one answer for one question. Post a new question for different scope.